# How to set URL for elfinder in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app, elfinder

I am using this module in yii2 framework but unable to set the correct URL 
https://github.com/simialbi/yii2-elfinder

```
 'connectionSets' => [
                'default' => [ // like elfinder roots
                    [
                        'class' => 'simialbi\yii2\elfinder\ElFinderConfigurationLocalFileSystem',
                        'path'  => '@webroot/uploads',
                        'URL'   => '@web/file/files' // HERE PROBLEM
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```

This is how I have defined URL `'URL'   => '@web/file/files'` where `file` is my controller and `files` is my action . 
Could you please let me know how exactly this URL show be passed in yii2 basic template .

`127.0.0.1:8080/project/elfinder/proxy/index?baseUrl=QHdlYi9maWxlL2ZpbGVz&path=/NewFolder/file_example_PNG_500kB.png&_t=1587811929`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out . 
Step 1 :- You need to set the URL managers properly

```
 'urlManager' => [
  'controller/action/<file:.*>' => 'controller/action',
]
```

Step 2 :- Create an action and add this code

```
public function actionYourActionName($file)
    {
        $image_path = YOUR_UPLOAD_PATH . basename($file);
        if (file_exists($image_path)) {
            return \yii::$app->response->sendFile($image_path, $file, [
                'inline' => true //OPTIONAL
            ]);
        } 
         return "What exception you want to throw";
    }
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient. If files are in web-accessible directory, it is better to build correct URL for it and let webserver to handle these requests. In other case at least handle cache headers correctly.

Comment: Well @rob006 Could you help me out how exactly it would work ? Meanwhile I am just continuing with the current code as of no choice .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`URL` point to web directory where files are stored (so this is the same directory as `path`, but as URL visible from web). In your case it probably should be `@web/uploads`.

Comment: I have used this earlier and it is giving me `Not Found (#404)` .

Comment: if i try to access it using my custom URL then it works . `..../uploads/NewFolder/abc.png`

Comment: Well, yeah, if you create `NewFolder/abc.png` then URL should look like `https://example.com/uploads/NewFolder/abc.png`. `@web/uploads` should point to `https://example.com/uploads` in this case.